# Remove unwanted lines in captcha text - opencv - python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, captcha

I trying to get text from captcha image using opencv.
Problem is text are masked with noise and it is complex to process with those horizontal line/noise.

Original image

[image]

My processed image :

[image]

not sure how to remove those horizontal lines and get text

Code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('captcha.jpg',0)

#display image in window
#cv2.imshow('image',img) #@param - windowname, image to be displayed

horizontal_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
#perform bitwise_and to mask the lines with provided mask
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=horizontal_inv)
#reverse the image back to normal
masked_img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(masked_img)
cv2.imshow("masked img", masked_img_inv)
cv2.imwrite("result2.jpg", masked_img_inv)

cv2.waitKey(0) # time for window to show image in milliseconds - 0 is infinite wait
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Edit : how to handle if text are in light color

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd better keep these lines and follow them to obtain the deformation field. After straightening, erasing will be easier, but more importantly, the characters will be restored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('captcha.jpg',0)

#display image in window
#cv2.imshow('image',img) #@param - windowname, image to be displayed

horizontal_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
#perform bitwise_and to mask the lines with provided mask
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=horizontal_inv)
#reverse the image back to normal
masked_img_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(masked_img)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(masked_img_inv,kernel,iterations = 3) # to remove blackline noise
cv2.imwrite("result1.jpg", dilation)
```

[image]

```
ret,thresh2 = cv2.threshold(dilation,254,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
thresh2=cv2.bitwise_not(thresh2)
# cv2.imshow("masked img", masked_img_inv)
cv2.imwrite("result2.jpg", thresh2)
```

[image]

```
cv2.waitKey(0) # time for window to show image in milliseconds - 0 is infinite wait
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Let me know if you have future queries.

Comment: is it possible to make those wavy word into straight one like bottom of all letter align in straight line

Comment: It not actually it depends on how the image is?. Are the words in white color...or does words has some contrasting color then the background if it follows the above condition then and then only we can do this

Comment: Aligning the words in the same line is difficult since we don't know which letters are present in the image. If we know then also it would be difficult to align in the straight line. though is great research topic.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for info, how to handle if letters are in light color (pls check modified question)

Comment: If you have lots of data then go through all of your datasets. find the dominating colors for letters like in above case white and light green. After finding out the dominating colors you can try 2 things 1st try to convert them to grayscale and get the decent enough threshold values to differentiate letters from the background. 2nd is to create your own kernel for specific 3-4 dominating color i.e if you apply this kernel to your image you will easily differentiate your letter and image background.