# Remove overlapped line over text with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, captcha

I'm processing images that have a line across the 4 letters. After some processing, i have get this result:

[image]

The only thing I can't get to do is remove that black line, so it can be more clear to be recognized with some OCR library. The final image should look like this (not losing quality of text):

[image]

I have tried to dilate the image, to try to fill the gaps, but I lose quality:

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("image.png", 0)
cv2_imshow(imagen2)

kernel = np.ones((0,0),np.uint8)
dilation2 = cv2.dilate(imagen2,kernel,iterations = 1) # to remove blackline noise
cv2_imshow(dilation2)
```

[image]

After that, I have tried to erode the image, but this doesn't work well, and I lose more quality:

```
kernel2 = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel2)
cv2_imshow(closing)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove unwanted lines in captcha text - opencv - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52374197/remove-unwanted-lines-in-captcha-text-opencv-python)

Comment: It is often a bad idea to show only the result of your preprocessing rather than the original image. Because there might be better ways that you don't think of.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the allowed character shapes, this is simply an impossible task. Because from an image processing point of view, nothing qualitatively distinguishes a character and the same character with a line across. So any "blind" processing that removes thin lines will as well destroy thin lines that can legitimately appear in the text, such as the space between characters, and is likely to worsen the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to apply erosion to the image to effectively remove the overlapped line across the letters, ensuring quality preservation during the image processing.

```
image = cv2.imread("captcha.png", 0)
cv2_imshow(image)
```

[image: click here to see img]

```
kernel3 = np.ones((2, 1), np.uint8) # Make changes in the kernel size to get better results
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(dilation2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel3)
cv2_imshow(closing)
```

[image: click here to see img]

```
# To save the image
cv2.imwrite("new_captcha.png", dilation2)
```